# Looking for a method to hook windows loadlibrary function

Tags: setwindowshookex

I want to hook all loadlibrary calls.
I know it is dirty but it is for a testing purpose.
What i want to do is replace on the fly one Dll by one other.
I have managed to hook with classical technics. The problem is the hook is set after target process startup. So i miss loadlibrary calls

Comment: This is _relatively_ easy to do from a custom debugger.

Comment: I tried but there is a problem: the target program is suspended at entry point but librairies are already loaded

Comment: You are talking about statically referenced DLLs, then. Those are not loaded with LoadLibrary anyway.

Comment: How are they loaded ? I have tried a software called spystudio and i see loadlibrary calls

Comment: They are loaded by the loader - I have no specific details.